# Magento v1.8.1.0 Cannot upload images

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

SOLVED: I figured out that it wasn't creating the image containers properly, I editted the onFilesSubmitted function to be as such:

```
onFilesSubmitted: function (files) {
        files.filter(function (file) {
            if(this._checkFileSize(file)) {
                alert(
                    this._translate('Maximum allowed file size for upload is') +
                    " " + this.miscConfig.maxSizePlural + "\n" +
                    this._translate('Please check your server PHP settings.')
                );
                file.cancel();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }.bind(this)).each(function (file) {
            this._handleUpdateFile(file);
        }.bind(this));

        var i = 0;

        (function($){
            $('.uploader #-container').each( function () {

                $(this).attr( 'id', files[i].uniqueIdentifier + '-container' );
                $(this).find( '.file-info' ).text( files[i].name );
                i++;
            });
        })(jQuery)
    },
```

When I try to upload an image in Magento 1.8.1.0, I can browse and choose an image to upload, but after selecting one the bar that would normally have the file name is blank. Clicking the remove, or upload file buttons afterward results in console errors, such as "Uncaught TypeError: file.cancel is not a function". I'm guessing this is because the file isn't getting populated after browsing and selecting an image to begin with.

I have spent time browsing other peoples issues with the image up-loader in this and different Magento versions, but have not found someone with this issue. It is a site that recently changed servers, but I unfortunately don't know if this was a previous issue, or a result of it changing servers. Any help is appreciated and if I missed someone else's question that matches this I apologize. Below are screenshots.

[file details not showing after selecting an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHMC8.jpg)

[js console error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6fyH.jpg)

Here is the code from my instance.js file, I turned on debugging and when I browse and select a file, it is console loggin my file details but it is showing like in the provided screenshot (blank)

```
(function(flowFactory, window, document) {
```

'use strict';
    window.Uploader = Class.create({

```
    /**
     * @type {Boolean} Are we in debug mode?
     */
    debug: true,

    /**
     * @constant
     * @type {String} templatePattern
     */
    templatePattern: /(^|.|\r|\n)({{(\w+)}})/,

    /**
     * @type {JSON} Array of elements ids to instantiate DOM collection
     */
    elementsIds: [],

    /**
     * @type {Array.<HTMLElement>} List of elements ids across all uploader functionality
     */
    elements: [],

    /**
     * @type {(FustyFlow|Flow)} Uploader object instance
     */
    uploader: {},

    /**
     * @type {JSON} General Uploader config
     */
    uploaderConfig: {},

    /**
     * @type {JSON} browseConfig General Uploader config
     */
    browseConfig: {},

    /**
     * @type {JSON} Misc settings to manipulate Uploader
     */
    miscConfig: {},

    /**
     * @type {Array.<String>} Sizes in plural
     */
    sizesPlural: ['bytes', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],

    /**
     * @type {Number} Precision of calculation during convetion to human readable size format
     */
    sizePrecisionDefault: 3,

    /**
     * @type {Number} Unit type conversion kib or kb, etc
     */
    sizeUnitType: 1024,

    /**
     * @type {String} Default delete button selector
     */
    deleteButtonSelector: '.delete',

    /**
     * @type {Number} Timeout of completion handler
     */
    onCompleteTimeout: 1000,

    /**
     * @type {(null|Array.<FlowFile>)} Files array stored for success event
     */
    files: null,


    /**
     * @name Uploader
     *
     * @param {JSON} config
     *
     * @constructor
     */
    initialize: function(config) {
        this.elementsIds = config.elementIds;
        this.elements = this.getElements(this.elementsIds);

        this.uploaderConfig = config.uploaderConfig;
        this.browseConfig = config.browseConfig;
        this.miscConfig =  config.miscConfig;

        this.uploader = flowFactory(this.uploaderConfig);

        this.attachEvents();

        /**
         * Bridging functions to retain functionality of existing modules
         */
        this.formatSize = this._getPluralSize.bind(this);
        this.upload = this.onUploadClick.bind(this);
        this.onContainerHideBefore = this.onTabChange.bind(this);
    },

    /**
     * Array of strings containing elements ids
     *
     * @param {JSON.<string, Array.<string>>} ids as JSON map,
     *      {<type> => ['id1', 'id2'...], <type2>...}
     * @returns {Array.<HTMLElement>} An array of DOM elements
     */
    getElements: function (ids) {
        /** @type {Hash} idsHash */
        var idsHash = $H(ids);

        idsHash.each(function (id) {
            var result = this.getElementsByIds(id.value);

            idsHash.set(id.key, result);
        }.bind(this));

        return idsHash.toObject();
    },

    /**
     * Get HTMLElement from hash values
     *
     * @param {(Array|String)}ids
     * @returns {(Array.<HTMLElement>|HTMLElement)}
     */
    getElementsByIds: function (ids) {
        var result = [];
        if(ids && Object.isArray(ids)) {
            ids.each(function(fromId) {
                var DOMElement = $(fromId);

                if (DOMElement) {
                    // Add it only if it's valid HTMLElement, otherwise skip.
                    result.push(DOMElement);
                }
            });
        } else {
            result = $(ids)
        }

        return result;
    },

    /**
     * Attach all types of events
     */
    attachEvents: function() {
        this.assignBrowse();

        this.uploader.on('filesSubmitted', this.onFilesSubmitted.bind(this));

        this.uploader.on('uploadStart', this.onUploadStart.bind(this));

        this.uploader.on('fileSuccess', this.onFileSuccess.bind(this));
        this.uploader.on('complete', this.onSuccess.bind(this));

        if(this.elements.container && !this.elements.delete) {
            this.elements.container.on('click', this.deleteButtonSelector, this.onDeleteClick.bind(this));
        } else {
            if(this.elements.delete) {
                this.elements.delete.on('click', Event.fire.bind(this, document, 'upload:simulateDelete', {
                    containerId: this.elementsIds.container
                }));
            }
        }
        if(this.elements.upload) {
            this.elements.upload.invoke('on', 'click', this.onUploadClick.bind(this));
        }
        if(this.debug) {
            this.uploader.on('catchAll', this.onCatchAll.bind(this));
        }
    },

    onTabChange: function (successFunc) {
        if(this.uploader.files.length && !Object.isArray(this.files)) {
            if(confirm(
                    this._translate('There are files that were selected but not uploaded yet. After switching to another tab your selections will be lost. Do you wish to continue ?')
               )
            ) {
                if(Object.isFunction(successFunc)) {
                    successFunc();
                } else {
                    this._handleDelete(this.uploader.files);
                    document.fire('uploader:fileError', {
                        containerId: this.elementsIds.container
                    });
                }
            } else {
                return 'cannotchange';
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Assign browse buttons to appropriate targets
     */
    assignBrowse: function() {
        if (this.elements.browse && this.elements.browse.length) {
            this.uploader.assignBrowse(
                this.elements.browse,
                this.browseConfig.isDirectory || false,
                this.browseConfig.singleFile || false,
                this.browseConfig.attributes || {}
            );
        }
    },

    /**
     * @event
     * @param {Array.<FlowFile>} files
     */
    onFilesSubmitted: function (files) {
        files.filter(function (file) {
            if(this._checkFileSize(file)) {
                alert(
                    this._translate('Maximum allowed file size for upload is') +
                    " " + this.miscConfig.maxSizePlural + "\n" +
                    this._translate('Please check your server PHP settings.')
                );
                file.cancel();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }.bind(this)).each(function (file) {
            this._handleUpdateFile(file);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    _handleUpdateFile: function (file) {
        var replaceBrowseWithRemove = this.miscConfig.replaceBrowseWithRemove;
        if(replaceBrowseWithRemove) {
            document.fire('uploader:simulateNewUpload', { containerId: this.elementsIds.container });
        }
        this.elements.container
            [replaceBrowseWithRemove ? 'update':'insert'](this._renderFromTemplate(
                this.elements.templateFile,
                {
                    name: file.name,
                    size: file.size ? '(' + this._getPluralSize(file.size) + ')' : '',
                    id: file.uniqueIdentifier
                }
            )
        );
    },

    /**
     * Upload button is being pressed
     *
     * @event
     */
    onUploadStart: function () {
        var files = this.uploader.files;

        files.each(function (file) {
            var id = file.uniqueIdentifier;

            this._getFileContainerById(id)
                .removeClassName('new')
                .removeClassName('error')
                .addClassName('progress');
            this._getProgressTextById(id).update(this._translate('Uploading...'));

            var deleteButton = this._getDeleteButtonById(id);
            if(deleteButton) {
                this._getDeleteButtonById(id).hide();
            }
        }.bind(this));

        this.files = this.uploader.files;
    },

    /**
     * Get file-line container by id
     *
     * @param {String} id
     * @returns {HTMLElement}
     * @private
     */
    _getFileContainerById: function (id) {
        return $(id + '-container');
    },

    /**
     * Get text update container
     *
     * @param id
     * @returns {*}
     * @private
     */
    _getProgressTextById: function (id) {
        return this._getFileContainerById(id).down('.progress-text');
    },

    _getDeleteButtonById: function(id) {
        return this._getFileContainerById(id).down('.delete');
    },

    /**
     * Handle delete button click
     *
     * @event
     * @param {Event} e
     */
    onDeleteClick: function (e) {
        var element = Event.findElement(e);
        var id = element.id;
        if(!id) {
            id = element.up(this.deleteButtonSelector).id;
        }
        this._handleDelete([this.uploader.getFromUniqueIdentifier(id)]);
    },

    /**
     * Complete handler of uploading process
     *
     * @event
     */
    onSuccess: function () {
        document.fire('uploader:success', { files: this.files });
        this.files = null;
    },

    /**
     * Successfully uploaded file, notify about that other components, handle deletion from queue
     *
     * @param {FlowFile} file
     * @param {JSON} response
     */
    onFileSuccess: function (file, response) {
        response = response.evalJSON();
        var id = file.uniqueIdentifier;
        var error = response.error;
        this._getFileContainerById(id)
            .removeClassName('progress')
            .addClassName(error ? 'error': 'complete')
        ;
        this._getProgressTextById(id).update(this._translate(
            error ? this._XSSFilter(error) :'Complete'
        ));

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(!error) {
                document.fire('uploader:fileSuccess', {
                    response: Object.toJSON(response),
                    containerId: this.elementsIds.container
                });
            } else {
                document.fire('uploader:fileError', {
                    containerId: this.elementsIds.container
                });
            }
            this._handleDelete([file]);
        }.bind(this) , !error ? this.onCompleteTimeout: this.onCompleteTimeout * 3);
    },

    /**
     * Upload button click event
     *
     * @event
     */
    onUploadClick: function () {
        try {
            this.uploader.upload();
        } catch(e) {
            if(console) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Event for debugging purposes
     *
     * @event
     */
    onCatchAll: function () {
        if(console.group && console.groupEnd && console.trace) {
            var args = [].splice.call(arguments, 1);
            console.group();
                console.info(arguments[0]);
                console.log("Uploader Instance:", this);
                console.log("Event Arguments:", args);
                console.trace();
            console.groupEnd();
        } else {
            console.log(this, arguments);
        }
    },

    /**
     * Handle deletition of files
     * @param {Array.<FlowFile>} files
     * @private
     */
    _handleDelete: function (files) {
        files.each(function (file) {
            file.cancel();
            var container = $(file.uniqueIdentifier + '-container');
            if(container) {
                container.remove();
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },

    /**
     * Check whenever file size exceeded permitted amount
     *
     * @param {FlowFile} file
     * @returns {boolean}
     * @private
     */
    _checkFileSize: function (file) {
        return file.size > this.miscConfig.maxSizeInBytes;
    },

    /**
     * Make a translation of string
     *
     * @param {String} text
     * @returns {String}
     * @private
     */
    _translate: function (text) {
        try {
            return Translator.translate(text);
        }
        catch(e){
            return text;
        }
    },

    /**
     * Render from given template and given variables to assign
     *
     * @param {HTMLElement} template
     * @param {JSON} vars
     * @returns {String}
     * @private
     */
    _renderFromTemplate: function (template, vars) {
        var t = new Template(this._XSSFilter(template.innerHTML), this.templatePattern);
        return t.evaluate(vars);
    },

    /**
     * Format size with precision
     *
     * @param {Number} sizeInBytes
     * @param {Number} [precision]
     * @returns {String}
     * @private
     */
    _getPluralSize: function (sizeInBytes, precision) {
            if(sizeInBytes == 0) {
                return 0 + this.sizesPlural[0];
            }
            var dm = (precision || this.sizePrecisionDefault) + 1;
            var i = Math.floor(Math.log(sizeInBytes) / Math.log(this.sizeUnitType));

            return (sizeInBytes / Math.pow(this.sizeUnitType, i)).toPrecision(dm) + ' ' + this.sizesPlural[i];
    },

    /**
     * Purify template string to prevent XSS attacks
     *
     * @param {String} str
     * @returns {String}
     * @private
     */
    _XSSFilter: function (str) {
        return str
            .stripScripts()
            // Remove inline event handlers like onclick, onload, etc
            .replace(/(on[a-z]+=["][^"]+["])(?=[^>]*>)/img, '')
            .replace(/(on[a-z]+=['][^']+['])(?=[^>]*>)/img, '')
        ;
    }
});
```

})(fustyFlowFactory, window, document);

Update: Running through the js doing a bunch of logging, looks like the file container isn't being created correctly, so I am looking into that atm

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be minimal, complete and verifiable. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I haven't modified any code on my own, just inherited the site (so I unfortunately can't pinpoint the cause easily), and am not getting anywhere from researching the issue on my own. I can provide code from specific files as needed, was just hoping for suggestions, or someone who possibly had the issue previously due to not being able to find a post with the same issue, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, posted the solution up above, but I changed the onFilesSubmitted function (it wasn't creating the file containers) to this:

```
onFilesSubmitted: function (files) {
        files.filter(function (file) {
            if(this._checkFileSize(file)) {
                alert(
                    this._translate('Maximum allowed file size for upload is') +
                    " " + this.miscConfig.maxSizePlural + "\n" +
                    this._translate('Please check your server PHP settings.')
                );
                file.cancel();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }.bind(this)).each(function (file) {
            this._handleUpdateFile(file);
        }.bind(this));

        var i = 0;

        (function($){
            $('.uploader #-container').each( function () {

                $(this).attr( 'id', files[i].uniqueIdentifier + '-container' );
                $(this).find( '.file-info' ).text( files[i].name );
                i++;
            });
        })(jQuery)
    },
```